# How to take a photo while UIImagePickerController type video mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

How to get one photo snap before recording video by using `UIImagePickerController` with media type `kUTTypeMovie`.

Here i need a photo from my camera before start recording video.

Please suggest me to achieve.

Comment: you just record the video AND THEN extract the first frame.

Comment: I need first frame before recording only or while recording.

Comment: what do you need it for? For creating video thumbnail?

Comment: thumbnail also fine but while recording only.

Comment: from the given link, http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-extract-a-uiimage-from-a-video-in-ios-9/ I can get 1st frame after recording, but I need while recording.

Answer (score 1):

hello you just record the video and extract the first frame or any time interval frame

`AVURLAsset* asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:fileURL options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator* imageGenerator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:asset];
[imageGenerator setAppliesPreferredTrackTransform:TRUE];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1) actualTime:nil error:nil]];
[self.imageView setImage:image];`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Pradip,  but i need this first frame while recording or  start record time.